# Failure to refresh function Regextract(Filename()) every time Google sheet opens from a mobile. How to trigger onOpen from a mobile?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

[Google sheet that fails to load filename()](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dtmsFNqGMFpAwjsnKFBTR0AGwqW_MuXAxYGL6evPRag/edit?usp=sharing)

I use daily sheets with the name of each day like this:

**01 January 2023 Oncall_Endorsement_Sheet**

**02 January 2023 Oncall_Endorsement_Sheet**

**03 January 2023 Oncall_Endorsement_Sheet**, and so on..

I used to add the date in each sheet by using the function of :
`=REGEXEXTRACT(FILENAME(), "\d{2} .* \d{4}")`

Where filename function is suggested by @Tanaike in the Appscript:

```
function Filename() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}

const sample = _ => "Loading..."; // Dummy.

function onOpen(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("CASES LIST");
  const range = sheet.getRange("C6");
  const formula = `=REGEXEXTRACT(FILENAME(), "\\d{2} .* \\d{4}")`;
  range.setFormula("=sample()");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.setFormula(formula);
}
```

It works well when the sheet is opened from any PC, but fails to run if the sheet is opened from a mobile phone like android.

[image]

Comment: Google Apps Script runs in Google's servers, not in the end device. The `onOpen(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that only runs when the file is opened from a server. The mobile Google Sheets app maintains a local copy of the file in the end device, and only synchronizes changes to the server. That means that some events do not get triggered, including to "on open" event. Your post does not pose a question. If you require more help, please ask a question.

Comment: As explained, `onOpen(e)` does not trigger when you use the mobile app. Consider posting a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you describe the end result you need, rather than describing the solution you think would solve the problem. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)